# Binding to the IsSelected property of the parent ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm attempting to bind the Visibility property of a `TextBlock` that's held within the ItemTemplate for a ListView to the IsSelected property of the TextBlock's parent ListViewItem.

With this markup, the TextBlock is always visible.

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Accounts}" Margin="60,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account.Name}"  
                                FontSize="24" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                    Show More Details...
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Notes:
 1. In case it makes any difference, this is WinRT; a Metro app written in C#.
 2. `boolConverter` is a fairly standard converter appears to work correctly.

Comment: Not sure about WinRT, but TemplatedParent is for ControlTemplates rather than DataTemplates. Try Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListViewItem instead.

Comment: Does it show binding errors in output view, I guess the TemplatedParent here would be ContentPresenter and not ListView

Comment: The enumeration Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.RelativeSourceMode doesn't (or doesn't appear to!) have a value for FindAncestor, unfortunately

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a resolution? I have a temporary code-behind solution but I am not quite satisfied.

Comment: Was any of you found a solution to this problem? Facing the same problem :(

Comment: I've put an answer to the similar question [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716656/how-to-bind-a-textblock-in-a-template-defining-the-listboxitem-of-a-listbox-to/19717121#19717121

Answer (score 4):

Use `Mode=FindAncestor`:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: FindAncestor doesn't appear to be an option in WinRT :|

Comment: Dont use it then. `FindAncestor` doesnt have to be supplied. `RelativeSource` with `AncestorType` should work ok.

Comment: @AngelWPF, AncestorType isn't available either, it looks like anything FindAncestor related isn't present in WinRT.

Comment: Uh... I wasn't aware of that. It seems crazy that they removed it, and I'm not sure what to use instead...

Comment: They didn't remove it, keep in mind that WinRT is much more like Silverlight than WPF, so most of the Silverlight restrictions apply.

Comment: @Murven, you're right of course... I didn't realize it wasn't in Silverlight either. I only use WPF

Comment: Silverlight 5 dose support FindAncestor, hopefully WinRT will as well

Comment: I came here from Google, looking for a solution to my non-WinRT problem and found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in this case you will have to use [ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209828%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)=ItemListView

Answer (score -1):

@Murven 's answer was close. This is what worked for me:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, ElementName=ItemListView Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
```

I had to use `DataContext.IsSelected` to access the context of the `ItemListView`.
Not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: This appears to bind to an `IsSelected` prooperty of the view model, not to the `ListViewItem`'s `IsSelected` property like the OP wants.