# How to bind a TextBlock in a template, defining the ListBoxItem of a ListBox, to the IsSelected property of the parent ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a List box defined like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="EmailList"
     ItemsSource="{Binding MailBoxManager.Inbox.EmailList}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMessage, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Grid.Row="1">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <usrctrls:MessageSummary />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The UserControl is defined like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.MessageSummary"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="600">

<UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid
      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="FlaggedImage"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Width="20"
                   Height="10"
                   Margin="0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Source="/Assets/ico_flagged_white.png" />

            <TextBlock x:Name="Sender"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding EmailProperties.DisplayFrom}"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_SenderRowTitle}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            <Grid x:Name="ImagesContainer"
                  Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="ImgImportant"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ico_important_red.png" />

                <Image x:Name="ImgFolders"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ico_ico_addtofolder.png" />

                <Image x:Name="ImgAttachment"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ico_attachment_lightgray.png" />

                <Image x:Name="ImgFlag"
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ico_flag.png" />
            </Grid>

            <TextBlock x:Name="Time"
                       Grid.Column="3"
                       Text="{Binding EmailProperties.DateReceived, Converter={StaticResource EmailHeaderTimeConverter}}"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding EmailProperties.Subject}"
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                   Margin="0,10" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="{Binding EmailProperties.Preview}"
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The MessageSummary is a UserControl. I would like to bind the foreground color of the ListBoxItems to whether the item is the one selected (IsSelectd property) in the ListBox,  i.e. I would like the ListBoxItem's foreground color (the TextBlocks) to be Black if not selected and Blue if the ListBoxItem is selected.

How can it be done?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the title of your question somehow related to the full question text?

Comment: Modified the question/title to make it more clear. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below demonstrates that. To pass the colour to your custom control you need to define `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`. Your control has to expose Foreground property which will be bound to `TemplatedParent's` `Foreground`. Inside your control you will have to bind a `TextBox` to the control's `Foreground`. This is the only way I see this can be done.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListBoxItem -->
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,10" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Duration="0" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Duration="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1"
                                                         Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid"
                              Background="Transparent">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground"
                                       Fill="{StaticResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                       Opacity="0" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />

                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       StrokeDashOffset=".5" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                       Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                       StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                       Opacity="0"
                                       StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <usrctrls:MessageSummary Foreground = {Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}} />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem >Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem >Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem >Item3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I think that you can't set triggers on the ListBox Style, at least the compiler scream about that :(

Comment: What is the error message? The code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: No Triggers/DataTrigger in WinRT. It is a Windows 8 WinRT application.

Comment: Could you please try out the updated code with the converter?

Comment: Hi Maxim, thx for the update. I tried these setters:

                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToBrushConverter}}" />

and

                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedToBrushConverter}}" />

however the converter is still not called.

Comment: Are there any messages in the Output/Immediate windows related to the binding?

Comment: The Convert class:
public sealed class IsSelectedToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
        if ( !( value is bool ) )
            {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

        return (bool)value ? TrueBrush : FalseBrush;
        }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
        {
        return null;
        }
    }

Comment: Error: BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter'. BindingExpression: Path='IsSelected' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter' (Name='null'); target property is 'Value' (type 'Object')

Comment: "Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem" is not WinRT, Mode can be "None" "Self" or "TemplatedParent" tried all 3.

Comment: BTW, this question is very similar, with no answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873900/binding-to-the-isselected-property-of-the-parent-listviewitem?rq=1

Comment: Got WinRT developer licence :) I have put a working code in the answer. The only option I see is override the default style of ListBoxItem and put the colour needed to the corresponding VisualStates

Comment: Thx, I am testing it now :)